# tricks on handling equivalence classes of equivalent classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, soft-question

I found myself always getting some difficulties in handling structures composing equivalence classes of equivalence classes. For example:

- localization of localization: $(B_f)_g$
- localization of quotient, or quotient of localization $(B/I)_f$, $B_f/I$
- quotient of quotient, $(B/I)/(J/I)$
- relative homology groups $C_n(X)/C_n(A)$
- and many other cases $\ldots$

I found myself frequently unwrapping the condition when two elements are the same in structures like this, and feel it's kind of hard writing proof with these structures, or checking well-definedness for maps between them. Are there some common tricks for this, maybe something like "flatten the equivalence classes"? Or is it just a case-per-case situation? And btw is there any pratical situations that we have to handle more than "2 fold" of equivalence classes? (Constructively the real number can be counted as a "3 fold" of equivalence classes of the natural number, but in pratical situation it seems unrelated)

Comment: I'm not sure there's a better general approach other than to work one-layer at a time, until you get to a sufficiently concrete level to reason with your assumptions.